# What is the value of π in this experiment(Bernoulli)?

Tags: probability, self-study, bernoulli-process

Experiment: You roll a fair 6-sided die 5 times.
Define the random variable x = number of times you rolled an even number.

The probability of exactly X successes in n trials for a Bernoulli process is:

**$$ \bigg(\frac{n!}{X!(n - X)!} \bigg) (\pi^{X}) (1 - \pi)^{n-X}$$**

What are the possible values for X? 0-5

What is the value of "n" in this experiment? 5

What is the value of "π" in this experiment?

What is the value of (1-π) in this experiment?

π is the percentage of chance that even numbers are rolled.

I was thinking "π " would be .5, because of 2,4,6 being the only options for rolling even numbers. Although, the dice is rolled 5 times so I don't know if that would change.

Comment: Because this is a self-study/homework question you should add the `self-study` tag by editing your question. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a straightforward binomial distribution. B(n,pi) with n= number of trials and pi=probability of an event. n=5 and pi=P(even number)=.5
n and pi are parameters of the distribution. they are independent of one another, so n=5 (or more or less) will not affect the value of pi.

Comment: This goes somewhat beyond the "hints and guidance" requested for answers to [`self-study`](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) questions